# Angular router does not react to Cognito redirect?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router, aws-amplify

When we use social login with AWS Cognito, Cognito sends a redirect to the browser to go to the `signin redirect` URL post signin.  The configured URL for that in this case is `http://localhost:4200/home/`.

When the app receives this redirect, it does go to `http://localhost:4200/home/` however the component displayed is still the one for `http:localhost:4200/signin/`.  If I manually refresh the page by selecting the URL and hitting enter, the the home component is displayed.

The router configuration looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'signin' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] },
  { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent, canActivate: [ UnauthGuard ] },
  { path: 'signout', component: SignoutComponent, canActivate: [ UnauthGuard ] }
]
```

So the app always redirects to `signin` at first.  The problem seems to be the double redirect.

Thoughts on how to fix this?

I tried it without the `Router` redirect.  I added a `welcome` page that is displayed with the `''` route.  When clicking login on this page, the app still reloads with the `signin` route initially (Where it leftoff ) and the redirects to the `home` route, however the signin component is still displayed.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, canActivate: [ UnauthGuard ] },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard ] },
  { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent, canActivate: [ UnauthGuard ] },
  { path: 'signout', component: SignoutComponent, canActivate: [ UnauthGuard ] }
]
```

### Update

See Answer.  Filed a bug report:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Even though the user is Authenticated after signing in with Google the first call like this post signing:

```
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((u) => {
        console.log('The user is : ', u)
      }).catch(e=>{console.log("NOT AUTHENTICATED YET")})
  }
```

Logs `NOT AUTHENTICATED YET`.  So the `AuthGuard` does not allow the user to pass through.

When the page is refreshed again then `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` return the user, so the guards direct the application to the correct page.